# Offline word processor for Chrome OS

Tags: gratis, offline, chrome-os, word-processor

A friend of mine has a Chromebook that he uses mostly offline, and he'd like a word processor that

- Is free, or very cheap
- Is compatible with Chrome OS
- Works off-line
- Can support multiple languages (not necessarily spellcheck, but typing) (Hebrew)
- Has a lot of functionality, closer to MS Word than Google Drive (aka Docs)

There's probably a Chrome extension or app that does something like this, but I can't find one.

Comment: You mentioned Docs but don't seem to be considering it as an option. Why's that? What specific feature(s) in MS Word are you looking for that's missing in Docs?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about language support, but if you know HTML or Markdown, the following are some **great** distraction-free text editors that I personally like to use a lot. Although, I know for a fact that they support at least Greek and Japanese if you enable their respective keyboard layouts because I've tried it.

Take note that they aren't really *word processors* in the typically used sense since they're WYSIWYM ("What You See Is What You Mean") rather than WYSIWYG ("What You See Is What You Get"), but if you know HTML or Markdown you can very easily use them for all kinds of documents. I do all the time. (Even though they're text editors, they do have support for various font styles, serif and sans-serif alike.)

- [StackEdit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackedit/iiooodelglhkcpgbajoejffhijaclcdg)
- [Writer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/writer/pnengefjfhgcceajaepbjhanoojifmog)
- [Writebox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/writebox/bbehjmjchoiaglkeboicbgkpfafcmhij)

If you like Markdown, the following are some distraction-free editors that I suggest you might try out. I haven't really used them that much as I've only installed them both *today*, but so far they seem to work really well, so it might be something you may want to at least *try*, eh? :)

- [Minimalist Markdown Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/minimalist-markdown-edito/pghodfjepegmciihfhdipmimghiakcjf)
- [Markdown](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown/iaidaeojkdnpahodojncgafnfaabiedf)

Comment: Nice, thanks for the answer. If it was for myself, I'd probably give these a try...but my friend isn't really all that tech-savvy, and he'd probably be better off with a WYSIWYG editor if he could get one. +1, in any event :)

Comment: No problem! :) I have an HP Chromebook 11 myself, so I know how difficult it can be to get ANY real port-over of familiar types of software. ^-^